# ggplot2 can't identify particular data.frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This issue is so strange to me. So I tried to create a radar chart using ggRadar from the interactive ggplot2 package ggiraphExtra, and for some reason it can't identify my particular data.frame. Emphasise "particular", other data.frames work fine with this plot statement but my particular data.frame won't.

Here's an example using the iris dataset, this example works fine.

```
library(ggiraph)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(moonBook)
library(ggiraphExtra)
library(ggplot2)

ggRadar(iris, mapping = NULL, rescale = TRUE, legend.position = "Top",
          colour = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 3, ylim = NULL,
          scales = "fixed", use.label = FALSE, interactive = FALSE)
```

But when I use this data.frame:

```
> my_dataset
     Case_1   Case_2   Case_3   Case_4   Case_5   Case_6   Case_7   Case_8
1    23.640   58.974   50.381    7.976   31.590    2.728   15.724    8.341
2    47.947   74.074   90.491   12.894   28.410   39.384   23.793   45.701
3    64.040   82.336   55.897   21.318   56.103   62.633   45.517   55.354
4    76.804   78.632   52.115   11.694    5.159   17.516   23.448   22.624
5   100.000   56.980   61.338   29.647    5.231    0.000   10.328   52.187
6    87.569   60.826   48.542   72.471    6.656    0.004   29.483   91.252
7    77.358   78.490   58.879   19.176   26.462    0.585   21.379   33.032
8    64.484   64.387   51.972   35.294   21.128    0.349   15.190   78.884
9    85.683   68.803   47.189   13.271    5.344    0.040   65.000   72.247
10   80.910   77.635   68.549    7.435    1.785    0.029   63.621   77.526
11   69.589   63.533   52.744    7.812   31.590    0.082   19.138   16.591
12   86.127   63.390   61.346    8.729   21.744    0.434   21.379   61.086
13   58.713   44.729   44.684   10.847   36.308    0.046   17.586   43.439
14   68.590   98.718   67.873   78.353   45.128   80.573   17.414   66.214
15   42.841   57.835   43.769   10.000   85.333    6.338   29.483   30.920
16   46.615   68.234   58.423    8.800   62.872   70.382   11.707   16.591
17   63.707   52.707   40.110   19.788   65.026    0.010   17.000   53.394
18   32.075   64.245    0.000   12.659  100.000  100.000   38.276   88.989
19   54.051   65.242   69.093    8.729   56.615    2.728   20.172   31.222
20   59.933   62.536   61.185   27.059   65.128    0.002   17.121   55.958
21   53.163   69.088   25.829   38.118   98.769   69.851   26.207   68.929
22   61.487   86.895   74.161   18.918   10.072    8.620   96.724   74.962
23   77.137   83.476   44.760   15.482   10.462   33.652   19.483   16.893

> class(my_dataset)
[1] "data.frame"
```

And use the same statement:

```
library(ggiraph)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(moonBook)
library(ggiraphExtra)
library(ggplot2)

ggRadar(my_dataset, mapping = NULL, rescale = TRUE, legend.position = "Top",
          colour = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 3, ylim = NULL,
          scales = "fixed", use.label = FALSE, interactive = FALSE)
```

It returns an error stating that object "variable" is not found.

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'variable' not found
```

SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Country.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Country.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Country.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Country.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] scales_1.1.0             reticulate_1.15          spotifyr_2.1.1           crayon_1.3.4             tm_0.7-7                
 [6] NLP_0.2-0                tibble_3.0.0             magrittr_1.5             wdman_0.2.5              rvest_0.3.5             
[11] xml2_1.3.1               zoo_1.8-7                rmarkdown_2.1            rio_0.5.16               shinydashboard_0.7.1    
[16] rsconnect_0.8.16         shiny_1.4.0.2            ggplot2_3.3.0            ggvis_0.4.5              httr_1.4.1              
[21] lubridate_1.7.8          stringr_1.4.0            data.table_1.12.8        tidyr_1.0.2              dplyr_0.8.5             
[26] imputeTS_3.0             googlesheets4_0.2.0.9000 GTT_0.0.1.902            gtrendsR_1.4.4           readr_1.3.1             
[31] ggiraphExtra_0.2.9       moonBook_0.2.3           reshape2_1.4.4           plyr_1.8.6               ggiraph_0.7.0           
[36] RSelenium_1.7.7         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] readxl_1.3.1       uuid_0.1-4         backports_1.1.6    systemfonts_0.2.0  tidytext_0.2.4     splines_3.6.3      mycor_0.1.1       
  [8] SnowballC_0.7.0    usethis_1.6.0      digest_0.6.25      htmltools_0.4.0    fansi_0.4.1        memoise_1.1.0      openxlsx_4.1.4    
 [15] remotes_2.1.1      genius_2.2.0       xts_0.12-0         askpass_1.1        forecast_8.12      tseries_0.10-47    prettyunits_1.1.1 
 [22] colorspace_1.4-1   haven_2.2.0        xfun_0.13          callr_3.4.3        jsonlite_1.6.1     glue_1.4.0         gtable_0.3.0      
 [29] ppcor_1.1          sjmisc_2.8.4       pkgbuild_1.0.6     semver_0.2.0       quantmod_0.4.17    stinepack_1.4      Rcpp_1.0.4.6      
 [36] xtable_1.8-4       foreign_0.8-75     htmlwidgets_1.5.1  RColorBrewer_1.1-2 ellipsis_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3    XML_3.99-0.3      
 [43] farver_2.0.3       nnet_7.3-12        tidyselect_1.0.0   labeling_0.3       rlang_0.4.5        later_1.0.0        munsell_0.5.0     
 [50] cellranger_1.1.0   tools_3.6.3        cli_2.0.2          generics_0.0.2     sjlabelled_1.1.3   devtools_2.3.0     evaluate_0.14     
 [57] fastmap_1.0.1      binman_0.1.1       processx_3.4.2     knitr_1.28         fs_1.4.1           zip_2.0.4          caTools_1.18.0    
 [64] purrr_0.3.4        nlme_3.1-144       mime_0.9           slam_0.1-47        tokenizers_0.2.1   compiler_3.6.3     rstudioapi_0.11   
 [71] curl_4.3           testthat_2.3.2     stringi_1.4.6      ps_1.3.2           desc_1.2.0         forcats_0.5.0      gdtools_0.2.2     
 [78] lattice_0.20-38    Matrix_1.2-18      urca_1.3-0         vctrs_0.2.4        pillar_1.4.3       lifecycle_0.2.0    lmtest_0.9-37     
 [85] bitops_1.0-6       insight_0.8.2      httpuv_1.5.2       R6_2.4.1           promises_1.1.0     janeaustenr_0.1.5  sessioninfo_1.1.1 
 [92] MASS_7.3-51.5      assertthat_0.2.1   pkgload_1.0.2      openssl_1.4.1      rprojroot_1.3-2    withr_2.1.2        fracdiff_1.5-1    
 [99] mgcv_1.8-31        parallel_3.6.3     hms_0.5.3          quadprog_1.5-8     grid_3.6.3         timeDate_3043.102  googledrive_1.0.0 
[106] TTR_0.23-6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following runs without issue on my computer. Can you share `sessionInfo()` and try with a new R session.

```
library(ggiraph)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(moonBook)
library(ggiraphExtra)
library(ggplot2)

ggRadar(iris, mapping = NULL, rescale = TRUE, legend.position = "Top",
        colour = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 3, ylim = NULL,
        scales = "fixed", use.label = FALSE, interactive = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
my_dataset <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ",", text = 
"Case_1, Case_2, Case_3, Case_4, Case_5, Case_6, Case_7, Case_8
23.640, 58.974, 50.381,7.976, 31.590,2.728, 15.724,8.341
47.947, 74.074, 90.491, 12.894, 28.410, 39.384, 23.793, 45.701
64.040, 82.336, 55.897, 21.318, 56.103, 62.633, 45.517, 55.354
76.804, 78.632, 52.115, 11.694,5.159, 17.516, 23.448, 22.624
100.000, 56.980, 61.338, 29.647,5.231,0.000, 10.328, 52.187
87.569, 60.826, 48.542, 72.471,6.656,0.004, 29.483, 91.252
77.358, 78.490, 58.879, 19.176, 26.462,0.585, 21.379, 33.032
64.484, 64.387, 51.972, 35.294, 21.128,0.349, 15.190, 78.884
85.683, 68.803, 47.189, 13.271,5.344,0.040, 65.000, 72.247
80.910, 77.635, 68.549,7.435,1.785,0.029, 63.621, 77.526
69.589, 63.533, 52.744,7.812, 31.590,0.082, 19.138, 16.591
86.127, 63.390, 61.346,8.729, 21.744,0.434, 21.379, 61.086
58.713, 44.729, 44.684, 10.847, 36.308,0.046, 17.586, 43.439
68.590, 98.718, 67.873, 78.353, 45.128, 80.573, 17.414, 66.214
42.841, 57.835, 43.769, 10.000, 85.333,6.338, 29.483, 30.920
46.615, 68.234, 58.423,8.800, 62.872, 70.382, 11.707, 16.591
63.707, 52.707, 40.110, 19.788, 65.026,0.010, 17.000, 53.394
32.075, 64.245,0.000, 12.659,100.000,100.000, 38.276, 88.989
54.051, 65.242, 69.093,8.729, 56.615,2.728, 20.172, 31.222
59.933, 62.536, 61.185, 27.059, 65.128,0.002, 17.121, 55.958
53.163, 69.088, 25.829, 38.118, 98.769, 69.851, 26.207, 68.929
61.487, 86.895, 74.161, 18.918, 10.072,8.620, 96.724, 74.962
77.137, 83.476, 44.760, 15.482, 10.462, 33.652, 19.483, 16.893")

ggRadar(my_dataset, mapping = NULL, rescale = TRUE, legend.position = "Top",
        colour = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 3, ylim = NULL,
        scales = "fixed", use.label = FALSE, interactive = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Either it's the dependencies or the object.Try seeing what `identical(my_dataset, my_other_dataset)` evaluates to where `my_other_dataset` is the one not working. You could also try to `as.data.frame(as.matrix(.))`  as see if that helps.

Comment: Interesting. I noticed when I used `unlist(my_dataset)`, the results for my data.frame were different to the data.frame you created from read.table(). The `identical()` function returned FALSE. There's something up with my data.frame haha. Btw I tried the `as.data.frame(as.matrix(.))`, but it removed the names of each column I set?

Comment: Try to share the output of `str(my_dataset)` in the post.

Comment: I figured out the issue. In a for loop I was subsetting too far in the data.frame, using [[1]], instead of [1]. Thanks for your help, it gave me good direction.